# Understanding the Pact Broker Workflow

Tags: pact

Knowing full well, there are many types of workflows for different ways of integrating Pact, I'm trying to visualize what a common work flow looks like.   I developed this [Swimlane for Pact Broker Workflow](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wu8op.png).

1. How do we run a Provider verification on an older Provider build?
2. How does this change with tags?
3. When does the webhook get created back to the Provider?
4. What if different Providers have different base urls (i.e. build systems)?
5. How does a new Provider build alert about the Consumers if the Provider fails?
6. Am I thinking about this flow correctly?

I've tried to collect my understanding from [Webhooks](https://github.com/pact-foundation/pact_broker/blob/master/lib/pact_broker/doc/views/webhooks.markdown), [Using pact where the consumer team is different from the provider team](https://github.com/realestate-com-au/pact/wiki/Using-pact-where-the-consumer-team-is-different-from-the-provider-team), and [Publishing verification results to a Pact Broker](https://github.com/DiUS/pact-jvm/tree/master/pact-jvm-provider-maven#publishing-verification-results-to-a-pact-broker-version-354) .   Assuming I am thinking about the problem the right way and did not completely miss some documentation, I'd gladly write up an advise work flow documentation for the community.

Comment: You might consider splitting your question up into multiple questions -because you have multiple questions here, people who can only answer one or two of them can't provide answers, which means you'll get less help.

Comment: I have answered the broader parts of your question (5 and 6), but your other specific questions would be better split into their own questions.

Comment: (I'm not trying to be unhelpful, I just don't know the answer to 1 or 2, and I'm not sure what you mean by 3).

Answer (score 2):

Your swimlane diagram is a good picture of the workflow, with the caveat that once everything is all set up, it's rare to manually start provider builds from the broker.

The provider doesn't ever notify the consumers about verification failure (or success) in the process. If it did, then you could end up with circular builds.

I think about it like this:

- The consumer tests create a contract (the Pact file).
- This step also verifies that the consumer can work with a provider that fulfils that contract (using the mock provider).
- Then, the consumer gives this Pact file to the broker (if configured to do so)
- Now that there's a new pact, the broker (if configured) can trigger a provider build
- The provider's CI infrastructure builds the provider, and runs the pact verification
- The provider's CI infrastructure (if configured) tells the broker about the verification result.

The broker and the provider's build system are the only bits that know about the verification result - it isn't passed back to the consumer at the moment.

A consumer that is passing the tests means the consumer can say "I've written this communication contract and confirmed that I can hold up my side of it". Failure to verify the contract at the provider end doesn't change this statement.

However, if the verification succeeds, you may want to trigger a consumer deployment. As Beth Skurrie (one of the primary contributors to Pact) points out in the comments below:

> Communicating the status of the verification back to the consumer is actually a highly important thing, as it tells the consumer whether or not they can be deployed safely. It is the missing part of the pact workflow at the moment, and I'm working away as fast as I can to rectify this.

Currently, since the verification status is information you might like to know about - especially if you're unable to see the provider's CI infrastructure - you might like to check out the pact [build badges](https://github.com/pact-foundation/pact_broker/wiki/Provider-verification-badges), which are a lighter way of checking the broker.

Comment: "Failure to verify the contract at the provider end doesn't change this statement, so it's not necessary to communicate the failure (or success) to the consumer's build system."

Actually, verification webhooks (allowing the consumer CI to be notified of a change in state of the verification status of a pact) will be coming very soon to the broker. As you point out, you would not want the same Consumer CI build to be re-triggered, or you would get in to a circular dependency, however, it could actually trigger the deployment of relevant consumer version if the pact was verified successfully.

Comment: Part 2, comment was too long. 
Communicating the status of the verification back to the consumer is actually a highly important thing, as it tells the consumer whether or not they can be deployed safely. It is the missing part of the pact workflow at the moment, and I'm working away as fast as I can to rectify this.

Comment: Thanks @BethSkurrie! I've updated the answer to include the extra information